# OMNeT++ inet::b to Int

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm trying to make an application that gets the size of an Ethernet chunk and stores it in a vector of ints. To get the chunk length I'm using the function provided by inet: `chunk->getChunkLength()`. Is there a way to convert the type `inet::b` to `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the size of a chunk in bits use this code:

```
int bitSize = b(chunk->getChunkLength()).get();
```

If you want to obtain the size in bytes use this way:

```
int byteSize = B(chunk->getChunkLength()).get();
```